# Как на Python узнать ключ активации Windows?

Tags: python, windows

Мне нужно узнать, какой у меня ключ активации Windows, но только на Python, это возможно как-нибудь сделать?

Comment: вопрос такой: где вы храните продукты и их данные

Comment: Обычно ключ активации на ноутбуке внизу распечатан. Можете фото сделать и с помощью питона и какой-нибудь OCR библиотеки попробовать распознать чего там напечатано.... Других вариантов с помощью Python'а решить эту задачу я не вижу.))))

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

Виндоус не даёт эту информацию программам, по той простой причине, что если бы любая программа могла бы читать ключи активации, то большинство вирусов и троянов занимались бы именно этим для последующий продажи прочитанного ключа. И наоборот, программе занимающийся честной деятельностью нет никакого дела, какой ключ использовался для активации Виндоус.

Кстати, в Виндоус 10 часто ключа активации вообще нет, а есть то, что называется цифровой лицензией.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос немного устарел, но все же а как Вам это: https://gist.github.com/Spaceghost/877110

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/867969)